# Will there ever be a "random" or "surprise me" button?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I'm learning everything I can about statistics and would love to have a "surprise me" button that would jump to a random question. (And of course, an easily-reachable "surprise me" button on that page, so I can keep jumping until something catches my eye.) I believe Wikipedia and Google have similar buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Exchange network has a sister site, [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) for standalone applications that provide an alternative interface or functionality for the site, or browser userscripts that enhance the actual sites themselves.

I would suggest searching there to see if something like exists, and if not, you could post a question asking.  Perhaps someone would be willing to whip up a userscript you could add to your browser.

Most modern browsers support userscripts - you can see details on the [script tag wiki page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) for browser support and installation instruction.

Comment: Good suggestion. Two partial answers that are in progress: http://stackapps.com/questions/1643/dice-stack-find-a-random-question and http://stackapps.com/questions/713/please-provide-a-mechanism-for-retrieving-random-questions

Answer (score 3):

For start, you may [browse by tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name); topic organisation is pretty good way of getting rid of time bias.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I currently do. But then I've occasionally followed a tagged topic's "Related" link and found something fascinating and informative that I would have never thought to search for in the first place. Hence, the "surprise me" idea.